# AsyncTask that checks current session based on time stored in shared preferences

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

I'm new to android, but in the interest of practicing and learning more I wanted to try to make a practice application that essentially allows the user to only be logged on within the minute that they first logged in. So in other words if you log in at 10:23, the user will be logged out as soon as the clock strikes 10:24. To do this, I log in via my `LoginActivity` I share the current minute in a `SharedPreferences` object. In the interest of making use of the `onResume()` method in my `AppActivity`, my application first opens the main activity,`AppActivity`, which then opens my `LoginActivity` in the `onCreate()` method of my `AppActivity` class.  Hopefully without being too redundant in my explanation, the goal is to call `sessionChecker_AsyncTask.execute()` in the `onResume()` method of my `AppActivity`.

Here's my login button found in `LoginActivity`:

```
login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int result = getTime();

            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putInt(SESSION, result);
            editor.commit();

            finish();
        }
    });
```

with helper method `getTime()` seen here:

```
private int getTime() {
        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        return time.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    }
```

As you can see I'm simply storing the current minute in a `SharedPreferences` object via my login button. Now from here, I wanted to create an `AsyncTask` in my `AppActivity` class that checks every 500ms (.5 seconds) if my current minute in `AppActivity` matches the minute that was stored in my `SharedPreferences` object, if not I want to essentially log the user out and send them back to the `LoginActivity`.

My issue is, I'm a bit confused about the types that I should be implementing in my `AsyncTask` for my `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()` methods. Also do I need the `onCancelled()` method, and would implementing it perhaps be useful for configuration changes within `AppActivity`?  As of now I'm thinking that I should set it up something like this:

```
private class SessionCheckerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Boolean>
    {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... minute_in_SharedPreferences) {
            //Create a thread that refreshes every 500ms that checks current time

            return false; //if the current time doesn't match the time in shared preferences
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

            /*
                If false was returned create a toast that says "Activity session has expired"
                then open the login activity again
             */
        }
    }
```

But then I'm also thinking that it shouldn't be necessary for `doInBackground()` to have a type at all. Instead `onPostExecute()` should only be called if the minute passed in `doInBackground()` doesn't match the current minute, but I'm not sure how to implement this in the typical `AsyncTask` format.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. In your doInBackground:

   ```
   do {
       if (getTime >= pref.getInt (SESSION, result)) break;
       try{
           Thread.sleep(500);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   } while (true);
   ```
2. In your onPostExecute:

   ```
   Toast.makeText(context, "Activity session has expired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   startActivity(new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class)
                   .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
   ```

P.S.: I think it's wrong way to remember a minute and then compare current minute with your saved one. In case when it was, for example, 21:59 you save int "21", but in next second it will be "22". Try to do the same, but with seconds. Then in doInBackground make float a = pref.getInt (SESSION, result), in do..while cycle make a+=0.5

Comment: I'm not there at home to check just yet, but from looking at it I'm pretty sure this would work great. Thanks so much!

Comment: please say when you check it if it's ok =) and check if activity exist in only one instance (for this I added Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK). Because it's no good if user will be logged in in many activities. If it does not work, you may send intent with flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP, then you are to override onNewIntent() method of your activity.

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the extra help on handling the intents as well, i wasn't aware about the use of intent flags before